# RuntimeWrappedException VS UnhandledException

Tags: c#, exception

Is this the best approach to handle both cases ?

```
 public static class Program
{
    //http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx
    //http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/dee46bde-9baa-46b6-889c-04e20dd04029
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404228.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS1058%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true

    [STAThread]
    public static Int32 Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool unhandledInstalled = false;
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;
            unhandledInstalled = true;

            var app = new App();
            app.DispatcherUnhandledException += DispatcherUnhandledException;
            return app.Run();
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // Notify
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var rwe = e as RuntimeWrappedException;
            if (rwe != null)
            {
                object wrappedException = rwe.WrappedException;
                MessageBox.Show(wrappedException.ToString());
            }

            if (unhandledInstalled)
                throw;

            // No handler has been installed but handle it anyway.
            UnhandledException(null, new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(e, true));
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }

    private static void DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
                                                     DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something here
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception handler in the Main() method will never run.  The Dispatcher.UnhandledException handler will prevent app.Run() from exiting due to an exception.  You set e.Handled = true in the event handler.  Don't make it silent, let the user know something went kaboom.

The "unhandledInstalled" variable is strange btw.  You installed one, it is always true.  If the code crashes *before* the try block then there's no reason to try to do something meaningful, something *really* bad happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it right, I haven't been able to test RuntimeWrappedException though,
and I just discovered that DispatcherUnhandledException handles everything inside the application, I thought it was strictly for Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() stuff.

Thank you,

```
        [STAThread]
    public static Int32 Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

            var app = new App();
            app.DispatcherUnhandledException += DispatcherUnhandledException;
            int run = app.Run();

            return run;
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // Notify & exit
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var rwe = e as RuntimeWrappedException;
            if (rwe != null)
            {
                object wrappedException = rwe.WrappedException;
                MessageBox.Show(wrappedException.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            throw;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }

    private static void DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
                                                     DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());

        // Decide if we exit or not
        // ...

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: You'd be better off posting this type of stuff as an amendment to your original question instead of creating your own answer. Unless you plan to accept your answer and it is different than the ones that have been proposed, amending your question with a summary of your solution is standard practice on Stack Overflow.